# Can't connect to Tor

Tags: configuration, help, linux

I am having error while running tor on my kali linux

> Sep 23 14:39:22.267 [notice] Tor 0.3.0.10 (git-5da2fc629a0670b3) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0f and Zlib 1.2.8.
>   Sep 23 14:39:22.267 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
>   Sep 23 14:39:22.267 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
>   Sep 23 14:39:22.270 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option '16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C'.  Failing.
>   Sep 23 14:39:22.270 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

UPDATE: This is my /etc/tor/torrc file (only relevant parts):

```
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
#HashedControlPassword 
16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
```

Comment: I think your config is incorrect, as the error indicates ... please post your /etc/tor/torrc

Answer (score 2):

You have accidently pressed the Enter when you was editing it - right here :

```
#HashedControlPassword 
16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
#CookieAuthentication 1
```

so it should be starting # symbol to make a line a comment. It was like this :

```
#HashedControlPassword 16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
#CookieAuthentication 1
```

So either restore the comment or add a # before 16:xxx line